# javascript final method

Tags: javascript, oop, final

Can a method in javascript be final? 
How to avoid it to be overriden by a subclass?

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to do this, due to the nature of JavaScript "inheritance".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the traditional sense, no, you can't have private/protected methods or prevent them from being overridden.

What you can do, however, is encapsulate methods in a scope and then simply not expose them:

```
function foo(){
    function bar(){
        // private function
    }

    this.doSomething = function(){
        bar();
    }
}
```

That's about as close as you can get.  I wrote an article on this a while ago: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/jsp/article.php/3600451/Javascript-Basics-Part-8.htm

You can also use `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__` to prevent access, but those aren't 100% cross-browser.

```
var x = {};
x.__defineGetter__('foo', function(){ return 10; });
x.__defineSetter__('foo', function(){});

x.foo = 'bar';
x.foo; // 10
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for what *member* you want to make secure.

Mike has mentioned `configurable` attribute for preventing from redefine -- delete. I'm adding this too.

```
function final(obj, members) {
    for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
        var m = members[i];
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(m)) {
            Object.defineProperty(obj, m, { 
                value: obj[m],
                writable: false,
                configurable: false 
            });
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
var obj = { foo: "bar" };
obj = final(obj, ["foo"]);

obj.foo = ""; // output will be empty but
obj.foo // now output's still bar.
```

### Another option

[Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze). But it's secures all members in object.

```
var obj = { foo: "bar" };
obj = Object.freeze(obj);

obj.foo = ""; // output is empty
obj.foo // output is still "bar".
```

Comment: You can make a single property frozen by marking it `configurable: false` and defining it in terms of a getter.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Configurable_attribute

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the language does not have a way of enforcing finality of object properties. You have to enforce this on your end. One way to be "pretty sure" is to use a naming convention that is extremely unlikely to be used in a subclass. something like

```
someobject.__property__
```

Would probably work pretty well. Another option is to use the hasOwnProperty() function to detect if a parent object already has a property before overwriting it with something else.

Comment: EcmaScript 5 has added property descriptors to allow for things like this.