# Disable overriding for JavaScript class method

Tags: javascript, class

Let's suppose I have a class called `Base` which has a method called `talk`, then let's create a derived class from `Base` called `Derived`. The `Derived` class can now shadow (or override) the `talk` function from `Base`. Is there any way to prevent this while keeping another method `walk` able to be overridable?

```js
class Base
{
    final talk()
    {
        console.log("I am a talking class!");
    }

    walk()
    {
        console.log("I am walking!");
    }
}

class Derived extends Base
{
    talk() // Should trow an error
    {
        console.log("I don't talk!");
    }

    walk() // Should NOT trow an error
    {
        console.log("I am not walking!");
    }
}

let der = new Derived();

der.talk(); // Should log "I am a talking class!"
der.walk(); // Should log "I am not walking!"
```

I searched the web for some implementations in TypeScript since it added various features to JavaScript's classes, but I couldn't find anything. I managed to create a working example in C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
  virtual void Start () final
  {
    std::cout << "Starting!";
  }
  
  virtual void End()
  {
    std::cout << "Ending!";
  }
};

class Derived : Base
{
public:
  void Start ()
  {
    std::cout << "Not starting!";
  }
  
  void End()
  {
    std::cout << "Not ending!";
  }
};

int
main ()
{
  Derived *newDerived= new Derived();
  newDerived->End();

  return 0;
}
```

Here's [the link](https://onlinegdb.com/nY1qPiWDM).

And it successfully fails! It returns:

```
main.cpp:13:8: error: virtual function ‘virtual void Derived::Start()’ overriding final function
   13 |   void Start ()
      |        ^~~~~
main.cpp:5:16: note: overridden function is ‘virtual void Base::Start()’
    5 |   virtual void Start () final
      |
```

**Note**: The use of the 'final' keyword relative in JavaScript has been already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796981/javascript-final-method), but in that case, most of the answers were talking about 'final in functions'. This question is about the use of the final keyword in JavaScript classes which (in my opinion since I'm not an expert in JavaScript) should have a different implementation or approach.

The answers to the question previously mentioned made use of the method `Object.defineProperty()` which does make the class methods immutable, but still allows them to be shadowed by a new method with the same name in a derived class (at least in the tests I made).

#### Solution

Here's the working code:

```js
"use strict";

class Base {
    #name;

    #makeMethodsFinal(methods) {
        for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(methods).length; i++) {
            Object.defineProperty(this, Object.keys(methods)[i], {
                writable: false,
                configurable: true,
                value: Object.values(methods)[i]
            });
        }
    }
    
    leave() {
      console.log("Bye!");
    }

    constructor(name) {
        this.#name = name;
        
        let finalMethods = {
            present: () => { console.log(`Hello! My name is ${this.#name}`); }
        };

        this.#makeMethodsFinal(finalMethods);
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    present() {
        console.log("This won't be printed");
    }

    leave() {
        console.log("It was nice seeing you!");
    }
}


let der = new Derived("Franco");

der.present();
der.leave();
```

As you can see, it makes use of a custom method that uses `Object.defineProperty()` in a different way from the answers provided making private properties of the class available.

Comment: I couldn't help but notice your *question* starts with a header reading *Solution*. That's not how Stack Overflow works. If you have a question, ask the question. You can answer your own question immediately if you so desire.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Not if the queston is closed, I suppose…

Comment: @Bergi True. More advice for the future than this question specifically :).

Comment: Yea, I put the solution header in the body since I resolved it, in case anyone wants to know the answer, as they do in other forums (I don't know if it's done well here).

Comment: I moved the solution to the bottom, as that is the more appropriate place than at the top.